# ERROR in rosinstall: Two ros roots defined in config

Tags: ros, installation, rosinstall, overlay

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i am trying to install an overlay of the ros-core and ros_comm stack but rosinstall throws the following error:

```
ERROR in rosinstall: Two ros roots defined in config, delete one: /work/ros/electric/ros /usr/stud/zhi/work/ros/roszhi
```

Where should i delete one ROS-ROOT? The $ROS_ROOT environment variable only includes one path and i didnt have this problem before... Do i recently have to change to change my ROS environment to create overlays with rosinstall?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30446/error-in-rosinstall:-two-ros-roots-defined-in-config-.../) by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2108 on 2012-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is warning you that you have two directories which are detected to be the "ros" stack.  And as that stack is special cased, having two copies of ros is not supported, and can lead to very unexpected behavior depending on which version is first in the configuration.  To fix the problem, edit your rosinstall file to remove the version of ros which you do not want to use.  (Usually /opt/ros/DISTRO/stacks/ros)

Also although it errors, it does complete it's operation.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Ruess](https://answers.ros.org/users/890/felix-ruess/) on 2012-05-30**:
I'm getting the same warning as Michi with rosinstall 0.6.16, however it doesn't seem to complete it's operation (the setup scripts are not generated).
I also need to overlay the ros stack with Michi's version for python3, so what exactly do I have to change to get this to install properly?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Michi,

I have the same problem when re-install morse with ROS. The problem is from rosinstall new version. I edit rosinstall executable file in /usr/local/bin/rosinstall and choose the old version 0.5.16. And it works fine.

---

Originally posted by [Tien Thanh](https://answers.ros.org/users/135/tien-thanh/) with karma: 231 on 2012-04-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-04-19**:
Thanks, this really seems to be a problem with new rosinstall versions...